# mongoid update_attributes changing datatypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Im creating a simple rails app to modify data in an existing mongo database.  I'm using mongoid for the interaction and can read/destroy objects just fine.

The problem comes is my mongo document has a 'node' which is a bunch of key value pairs with vary depending on the record.  When i load the record like so:

```
MongoObject.find(BSON::ObjectId('ABC1234567890'))
 => #<MongoObject _id: ABC1234567890,  node: {"totallogins"=>11, "id"=>"logIns"}>
```

I'm using a standard rails form to update the values so the post data looks like:

```
{"commit"=>"Edit", "utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"ABC1234567890", "mongo_object"=>{"node"=>{"totallogins"=>"12", "id"=>"logIns"}}
```

If i then do:

```
@mongo_object.update_attributes(params[:mongo_object])
```

This works but changes the datatype of "totallogins" from an int to a string because the post data is a string.

Now active record deals with this itself but i need a solution that will work with mongoid.

Any ideas how i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. Unfortunately i can't as the fields for node are totally dynamic so i can't define them. I've come up with the following solution but its a tad ugly:

```
@mongo_object.node.each do |k,v|
  new_value = params[:mongo_object][:node][k.to_sym]
  new_value = new_value.to_i if v.class == Fixnum

  @mongo_object.node[k] = new_value
end

@mongo_object.save
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the node an embedded_document, then you can explicitly set the field types when you declare them.

```
class Node
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :mongo_object

  field :totallogins, type: Integer

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/ mentions how to deal with types; perhaps make sure your type is an Integer?